# No highlighting when button is pressed after using a shape xml file for the background

Tags: android

I have a button with a text, icon above the text and an xml file defining it's shape set to the background. After setting the background to a custom shape the button loses it's standard highlighting when pressed. Could someone please tell me how to fix this? Btw I rather not want to use an extra animation file.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_top"

    android:text="Press"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/transport"

    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_top_shape"
    android:shadowColor="#8F8F8F"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewTitle"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Below is the file defining the shape of the button named "button_top_shape".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
 <corners
    android:radius="0dp"
    />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerX="35%"
    android:centerColor="#000000"
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:type="linear"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#878787"
    />

</shape>
```

Comment: u need to use a selector resource for ur button's background; so instead u can also extend an AppCompactActivity(currently ur activity class extens a plain old activity class) which will highlight the button;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight your button when pressed then use

round.xml in drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_pressed="true" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
                <corners android:radius="3dip" />
                <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
                <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#e4d46f" android:endColor="#e4d079"  />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_focused="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
                <corners android:radius="3dip" />
                <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c7cf2d" />
                <solid android:color="#e9da67"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
                <corners android:radius="3dip" />
                <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#e7d851" />
                <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#e4d079" android:endColor="#87cf8d" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

In your button add

```
 android:background="@drawable/round"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xml file and make the required changes...Hope this helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true">
  <shape>
      <stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#80FFFFFF" />

  <corners android:radius="25dp" />

  <gradient android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#87CEEB"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff" />

    </shape>  
</item>

  <item>
   <shape>
       <stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#80FFFFFF" />

    <corners android:radius="25dp" />

  <gradient android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#87CEEB"
        android:endColor="#87CEEB"
        android:startColor="#87CEEB" />

    </shape>

 </item>
</selector>
```